# Trying to prove that a propagator only depends on the difference of coordinates if our system has translational symmetry

Tags: quantum-mechanics, propagator

As the title says, I'm trying to prove that if a system is translation invariant, then its propagator depends only on the difference of coordinates. That is to say
$$K(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{x}';t - t_0) = K(\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{x}';t-t_0)$$
where
$$K(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{x}';t - t_0) = \langle \boldsymbol{x}| e^{-i H (t - t_0) / \hbar} |\boldsymbol{x}' \rangle$$
I've tried to prove this in two ways, but I'm stuck in some things.

First attempt: If we have translational symmetry, then $|\boldsymbol{x} \rangle = |\boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{a} \rangle = e^{-i \boldsymbol{p} \cdot \boldsymbol{a} / \hbar} |\boldsymbol{x} \rangle$
\begin{align*}
\Rightarrow K(\boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{x}' + \boldsymbol{a};t - t_0) &= \langle \boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{a}| e^{-i H (t - t_0) / \hbar} |\boldsymbol{x}' + \boldsymbol{a} \rangle\\
&= \langle \boldsymbol{x}| e^{i \boldsymbol{p} \cdot \boldsymbol{a} / \hbar} e^{-i H (t - t_0) / \hbar} e^{-i \boldsymbol{p} \cdot \boldsymbol{a} / \hbar} |\boldsymbol{x}' \rangle
\end{align*}
I don't know what else to do here. Couldn't I just sum the exponents? I wouldn't arrive anywhere. I can't see where the dependence from the difference of coordinates could be deduced from here.

Second attempt: If there's translational symmetry, then $[H,\boldsymbol{p}] = \boldsymbol{0}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\langle \boldsymbol{x} | e^{-i H (t - t_0) / \hbar} | \boldsymbol{x}' \rangle &= \int\limits_{\mathcal{V}} \langle \boldsymbol{x} | \boldsymbol{p} \rangle \langle \boldsymbol{p} | e^{-i H (t - t_0) / \hbar} | \boldsymbol{x}' \rangle \text{d} \boldsymbol{p}\\
  &= \frac{1}{(2 \pi \hbar)^{n/2}} \int\limits_{\mathcal{V}} \langle \boldsymbol{p} | e^{-i H (t - t_0) / \hbar} | \boldsymbol{x}' \rangle e^{i \boldsymbol{p} \cdot \boldsymbol{x} / \hbar} \text{d} \boldsymbol{p}\\
  &\stackrel{?}{=} \frac{1}{(2 \pi \hbar)^{n/2}} \int\limits_{\mathcal{V}} e^{-i H (t - t_0) / \hbar} \langle \boldsymbol{p} | \boldsymbol{x}' \rangle e^{i \boldsymbol{p} \cdot \boldsymbol{x} / \hbar} \text{d} \boldsymbol{p}\\
  &= \frac{1}{(2 \pi \hbar)^{n}} \int\limits_{\mathcal{V}} e^{-i H (t - t_0) / \hbar} \ e^{\frac{i}{\hbar} \boldsymbol{p} \cdot (\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{x}')} \text{d} \boldsymbol{p}\\
\end{align*}
The step over which there's a "?" is the one I'm not sure of, since I'm commuting the eigenstate $|\boldsymbol{p} \rangle$ with $H$, not the operator $\boldsymbol{p}$. Although I arrived at the dependence I'm looking for, I doubt it is the right answer. Does this attempt hold any ground or is it wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As a hint, you may want to use the fact that $H | p \rangle = E | p \rangle$, where $H$ is the Hamiltonian operator and $E$ is an energy eigenvalue.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I'm assuming this applies to my second attempt, right? And yes, you're right, that's why I edited my question so that $e^{-i H (t-t_0) / \hbar}$ is inside the integral (in my second attempt).

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the line with the question mark in the second attempt. Maybe to be a bit more direct, I think the language of "commuting the eigenstate $|p\rangle$ with $H$, not the operator $p$" is a little off. You shouldn't move an operator outside of a "bra ket sandwich," but you can do a number. Also note that for a particle without a potential, $E$ is a function only of $p$ and not $x$.

Comment: Since $[H,p]=0$ in your first attempt surely you can just commute the exponents around - this gives $K(a+x,a+x')=K(x,x')$ which is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Andrew Ok, I once again thank you for your help.

Comment: @jacob1729 Sure, as I said in my question, I could just add the exponents and I would arrive to what you have said, but where does the dependence on the difference of coordinates arrive from there? I'm probably missing a very obvious hint in my first attempt, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me just write out your first argument a little differently, because it does work. Suppose the translation operator is $\hat{T}_a$ so that:

$$\hat{T}_a |x \rangle = |x+a \rangle$$

Then your first argument reads as:

$$K(a+x,a+x') = \langle x | \hat{T}_a^\dagger e^{_-i\hat{H}t} \hat{T}_a | x' \rangle $$

the translation operator is unitary, that is $\hat{T}_a^\dagger = \hat{T}_a^{-1}$ and the statement of translation invariance is precisely that $\hat{T}_a^{-1}e^{-iHt}\hat{T}_a = e^{-iHt}$. That is: translating, time evolving, then translating back is the same as just time evolving if the system is translationally invariant. Thus we arrive at:

$$K(a+x,a+x') = K(x,x')$$

but we can choose any $a$ we like, so in particular pick $a=-x'$ to obtain:

$$K(x,x')=K(x-x',0) = \tilde{K}(x-x')$$

ie is a function of only $x-x'$.

Comment: Is it really that easy? I just had to take the particular case in which $\boldsymbol{a} = \boldsymbol{x}'$? Because I did arrive to your third equation, it just didn't occur to me that $\boldsymbol{a}$ could be whatever I wanted. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @RMC777 yes this is all. Since you can translate by any $a$ you can fix one of the arguments to be $0$ and then the other is $x-x'$.